# Python multiprocessing pool with imported function

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

Using windows and python 3.6 I am having trouble with the multiprocessing once I import the function which is to be mapped.
This code works (gives output [2, 12, 30, 56, 90]):

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
def f(x,y):
    return x*y

if __name__ == '__main__':
    args=[(1,2),(3,4),(5,6),(7,8),(9,10)]
    with Pool(4) as p:
        result=p.starmap(f,args)
    print(result)
```

Now I move the function f to a different .py file called 'test' and instead import it:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from test import f    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    args=[(1,2),(3,4),(5,6),(7,8),(9,10)]
    with Pool(4) as p:
        result=p.starmap(f,args)
    print(result)
```

with test.py only containing:

```
def f(x,y):
    return x*y
```

Running this leads to an infinite loop (doesn't return anything with cpu usage high).

What is causing this and is there a way to fix it? I have successfully got multiprocessing to work on a program by copying all the code into one huge .py which obviously is not ideal.

Comment: This seems to be a Windows-specific problem: I can't reproduce it on OS X or Linux.

Comment: Could you please add exact version of Python you are using?

Comment: I can't reproduce this using Python 3.6.6 on Windows.

Comment: @Sallena: Does this reproduce when starting a fresh Python session? Do you use any IDE?

Comment: I have this problem using python 3.6.5, anaconda(spyder) on windows 10.

Comment: Like others, I cannot actually reproduce the problem (Linux though). But one more question, if you send `SIGINT` (`^C`) to your hung controlling process, what would the stack trace say, what did it do at the time?

Comment: I can't figure out how to break the loop. I put it in 'try:' with 'except KeyboardInterrupt: /n sys.exit()' after but nothing I pressed seemed to spot the process. Any ideas?

Comment: Either remove the `try/except KeyboardInterrupt` or just put `raise` on a line before `sys.exit()` which will re-raise the exception caught.

Comment: Tried that but still does not let me break it

Comment: I have a similar problem on linux